# Android horizontal and vertical layout development

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-scrollview, android-scroll

This is a stupid question but i am in middle of an application in which i want to develop a layout as :

[image: Layout]

This layout scrolls vertically as well as horizontally. I thought to take a scroll view and under that table view, but how to make it scrollable horizontally also. The data is coming from the web service so I don't know what amount of data is going to come.

So please guide me.

Comment: Hi you can make this , just try to implement this tutorial :http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/android-scrollview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good idea to use two scroll view. But if it is needed you can do one thing :

Create XML layout as :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_vertical_table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="*" >

            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And insert records or rows programmatically in this table as :

```
TableLayout tableLayoutTransactionLineHeading = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
for(int j=0; j<rows; j++){      
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView lineno = new TextView(this);
    lineno.setText(lineNo[j]);
    lineno.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    lineno.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tableRow.addView(lineno);

    View v = new View(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50));
            tableRow.addView(v);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0f));
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad user experience to have both scrolling horizontally and vertically. What I sugest you is to have only one and what I see in your example the horizontal one. If is mandatory to have both you can create a ListView and into your adaptor when you create the cell to have a Horizontal ScrollView as a parrent where to ad with inflate the view childs for your horizontal ScrollView.